# Unknown partition table type error from u-boot running on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, sd-card, u-boot

I've been trying to run the Linux on my **Raspberry Pi 4** board. But, I couldn't even achieve running the ***u-boot*** properly. The board launches up without any problem and starts running the ***u-boot***. The ***u-boot*** then tries to read the contents of the SD card but it cannot. This is how the terminal screen looks like:

```
U-Boot 2021.01 (Aug 07 2021 - 16:54:46 +0300)
DRAM:  7.9 GiB
RPI 4 Model B
MMC:   mmcnr@7e300000: 1, emmc2@7e340000: 0
Loading Environment from FAT... ** No partition table - mmc 0 **
... (Some unrelated info here)
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
** No partition table - mmc 0 **
Card did not respond to voltage select! : -110
```

I believe that the partitioning of my SD card has no problem as I've followed the SD Card preparation tutorials carefully. Here you can see the output produced by `fdisk` tool below.

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 119,9 GiB, 127865454592 bytes, 249737216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbb50dfe5

Device         Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *     2048 249737215 249735168 119,1G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Whenever I call the `mmc part` or `fatls mmc 0:1` commands, I see the following error prompts.

```
U-Boot> mmc part
## Unknown partition table type 0
U-Boot> fatls mmc 0:1
** No partition table - mmc 0 **
```

What do you think that I'm doing wrong? How should I continue searching for a solution?

By the way, the ***u-boot*** that I'm using was compiled using `aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu-gcc` and it had been cloned from the mainline [repo](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot).

Comment: Is this with fedora?

Comment: @defim The host operating system was Ubuntu

Comment: Please check that the files in /boot/efi/ and overlays/ match your uboot. This was for me the reason for the "-110" error with 4GB raspberry